# Need to check is_archive during init

Tags: hooks, archives

I need to check if a page is an archive or not, before my plugin does some URI manipulations.  These manipulations only work before `wp` but if I perform them first and then check `is_archive`, the check will always return false.

How can I check `is_archive` (or achieve the same end result) during a pre-`wp` hook?

It would be great if we could pass `is_archive` a postid to check, but it doesn't work that way.

**EDIT**:  I realize perhaps I'm explaining myself poorly, as archives don't even HAVE postids, as far as I know.  I just need some way to check if the current URI is an archive or not, before `wp` fires.

**EDIT**:  On further experimenting, it appears that my URI manipulations can't take place any later than `init`, I think because by that point WP has already done its rewriting and such.  So, I either need a way to check for an archive page status, within `init`, or do URI rewriting after `init`, either approach is fine with me as long as it gets the intended result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I could come up with, within `init` like you said ! Even if you print the `$GLOBALS` array, there is no way to check if the current page is an archive, `is_archive` is also set to blank! But if you check the `$_GET` array, the `q` variable contains the current archive type being displayed. Using this I came up with a hack, I cannot guarantee you if it will work always! But you can try something around this!

```
<?php

    add_action('init', 'q');

    function q()
    {
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($_GET);
        //echo '</pre>';

        $q = $_GET['q'];

        //Here you can substitute other 'archive' terms, say 'author', 'date' or '<custom taxonomy name>'. Use a switch case or nested if-else to check all the archive terms in your environment!
        $pos = strpos($q, 'category');
        if($pos !== false )
            echo "CATEGORY ARCHIVE";
    }
```

Hope this one works!

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that I can't run this any later than `init`, I've updated my question to reflect that.  Thanks though, any other creative ideas?

Comment: Please check the updated code and description now!

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'm afraid I'm not following it though, and it appears not to work.  It seems to be looking for a query string parameter called 'q' but no such parameter exists, so I'm unclear on what it's supposed to do.  Where would `$_GET['q']` come from?

Comment: It comes from the $_GET array! Uncomment and check the print_r that I've commented out. It has the variable 'q'. Can you please post your code? What kind of an archive are you trying to check... 'author', 'category' or some other taxonomy? See the archive types here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive

Comment: Aha, I think I see what you meant, if I am on default permalinks (i.e. "ugly" permalink) there is a cat parameter passed by default (not category).  Unfortunately I am always using "pretty" permalinks, so there is no such parameter in the query string.  =(

Comment: Even I'm using pretty permalinks! What format are you using for the permalinks? I'm using %postname%...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1544/discussion-between-jonathan-and-rutwick-gangurde)

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer.  While it doesn't work for me using "pretty" permalinks for some strange reason, it does work using default permalinks so for some people, this might be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! You had left the chat yesterday, so just reminding here, try this solution in some other WP installation. It works. Best of luck!